# Blender CLI does not work when blender is installed through Windows Store

Tags: command-line, windows

In order to have a blender version manager I installed blender through the Windows store. When you install through the windows store it seems that they store the file in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BlenderFoundation.xxx`. When files are in the WindowsApps folder access to them is restricted. Just to have access to the folder I had to run the terminal as administrator. Still when I got to the folder and attempted to run the executable I got:

```
Program 'blender.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ .\blender.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\blender.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I even changed my ExecutionPolicy to AllSigned. Still I do not have access. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if the only way to have access to the CLI is to download blender outside of the windows store.